# Does $f(x)/x^a \rightarrow \infty$, $f(x)x^a \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow 0$ imply $\log f(x)/\log x \rightarrow 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Suppose a function $f(x)$ satisfies that for every $a > 0$, $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}f(x)x^{-a} = \infty$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}f(x)x^{a} = 0$. Then must $\log f(x)/\log x \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow 0$?

Comment: @Svetoslav: I've just tried various functions like $\log x$, $\exp\sqrt{\log x}$ and they all seem to work, however I'm unsure how to show it rigorously for any function that obeys these properties.

Comment: Translate your question into $g\to \infty$, $f+ag\to\infty$, $f-ag\to -\infty$ for all $a>0$. Does $f/g\to 0$? (the answer is yes).

Comment: @A.S. The limit needs to be taken from the right-hand side, of course.

Comment: @Dr. I'm not sure I follow. The limit can be taken any way you want it - as long as all limits are taken in the same manner.

Comment: @A.S.  If we are restricting this to real analysis, then $x>0$ is required, else $x^a$ is undefined for negative values of $x$ in general.  And the hypothesis is applicable for all $a>0$.

Comment: @Dr. Of course $\lim h$ is taken over domain of $h$ only. In this case its over $x>0$ by a mere presence of $\log x$. I might have misunderstood your comment directed at my general reformulation as concerning the statement itself rather than further particular application.

Comment: A.S. I gave your comment a +1.

Comment: @Dr. The purpose of the @ part of your comment didn't come through well for me then. +1 ;).